# Black lines appearing on desktop

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, hardware-failure, graphics

I notice of late, I keep getting black lines going across the screen on the desktop.

I was wondering if anyone knew what causes this and how to fix the issue.

I have attached a picture with the lines circled.[image]

I have checked the drivers with `Snappy Driver Installer Origins` but it does not show any graphics driver updates

Comment: Are the lines always on the same spot? Do they appear after you move a window? Is the image a photo or screenshot?

Comment: @LPChip the position of the lines can vary, as can the number of lines.
I think I may have noticed a pattern though, it seems to happen when WPS Office plays up. If WPS office crashes (Which it tends to do frequently) these black lines seem to appear